# How to return a specific fields using Pymongo and MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to return just two fields from my MongoDB database and this query correct sends back my username and posts from the client:

```
db.users.find({'email_address': /^johnny/}, {'username': 1, 'user_posts': 1, '_id': 0});
```

I'm trying to switch this to PyMongo so I can query in Python and my query looks like this:

```
regx = Regex('^{0}'.format('johnny'))
query = {'postcode': regx}, {'username': 1, 'user_posts': 1, '_id': 0}
user_list = mycol.find(query).limit(5)
```

The bit where it's failing is here:

```
{'username': 1, 'user_posts': 1, '_id': 0}
```

As without this filter the documents are sent in full fine.  With that I get this error message from PyMongo:

```
TypeError: filter must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, or any other type that inherits from collections.Mapping
```

I assume that my filter is malformed and it's no longer a dictionary so have tried various alternatives of wrapping in quotes and then .format() etc but cannot seem to hit the magical combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was quite easy.. I just needed to have two dictionaries.  1 for the query and the other for the filter.

```
regx = Regex('^{0}'.format('johnny'))
filter_stuff = {'username': 1, 'user_posts': 1, '_id': 0}
```

Then just build the full query as follows:

```
user_list = mycol.find(query, filter_stuff).limit(5)
```

Comment: `filter` is a python built-in so I'd avoid using it as a variable. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the following is not a dictionary but a tuple of two dictionaries:

```
query = {'postcode': regx}, {'username': 1, 'user_posts': 1, '_id': 0}
```

if you wanted to use it directly you could do it with

```
user_list = mycol.find(query[0], query[1]).limit(5)
```

but probably best to actually assign it to two separate variables like so

```
query, filter = {'postcode': regx}, {'username': 1, 'user_posts': 1, '_id': 0}
```

and then

```
user_list = mycol.find(query, filter).limit(5)
```